# Regex to find image src/path from attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, find

if my html is

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg);"></div>
```

And I get style attribute like..

```
var img_src = $('div').css('background-image');
```

So output is

```
url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")
```

Any regex or some basic thing to find image src/path 100% ? like

```
http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg
```

100% I mean cross browser, It should work 100%

I not sure about output from `var img_src = $('div').css('background-image');` has pattern like this in all browsers , If "yes" so I can do `.replace()`function

Playground : http://jsbin.com/apalat/1/edit

Comment: Why would you need a regex for this? Why not just fetch the element's `background-image` property?

Comment: Sorry sorry Edited , I want pure image src like `http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg` @Pekka웃

Comment: Can you guarantee that someone has not written `background-image: url('http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg');"` with the URL surrounded by quotes? It is valid CSS to have quotes around a URL - they are optional in the specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$("code").html(img_src.slice(5, -2));
```

#### [CHECKOUT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S4GPz/)

### Update:

`For 'chrome'` because chrome doesn't add `'"' quotes:`

```
var img_src = $('div').css('background-image');

$("code").html(img_src.slice(5, -2));

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') >= 0) {
   $("code").html(img_src.slice(4, -1));
}
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S4GPz/2/)

Comment: Is my `img_src` will output like `url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")` in all browsers right ?

Comment: Oh yes yes. This seems to be.

Comment: In Chrome 23, your fiddle shows `ttp://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jp` as output.

Comment: Yes in chrome will show `url(http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg)`

Comment: Because in Firefox `img_src = url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")` (Firefox added some quotes) and in Chrome it is `url(http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg)` so the slicing is wrong

Comment: @andyb You are absolutely correct and i just updated the answer.

Comment: [Browser detection via the userAgent is rarely a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). It would be cleaner to detect quotes. Plus, this will _still_ not work in Safari since the userAgent does not contain `Chrome` but the engine **will not** add surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need regex, just cut the string...

http://jsfiddle.net/BHcsQ/2/

```
var s = 'url("http://domain.com/randompath/random4509324041123213.jpg")';
var s_sub = s.substring(5, s.length-2);

alert(s_sub);
```